# Save order of accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I recently upgraded my app to v4.2.4 from v4.2.0. It turns out that save orders have been changed for nested attributes. Is there a way to define which 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' is saved first. I am able to notice the change because each model has before_create callbacks.

#### Update:

Problem starts when we switch from v4.2.0 to v4.2.1.

#### Update 2: Why order matters?

Because we have a single sign up form for `customer`, which `accepts_nested_attributes_for` both `creditcard` and `subscription`. Order of `creditcard` and `subscription` callbacks matter because once the creditcards' `before_create` callback is called we can create the subscription remotely on stripe.

#### Update 3:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecored::Base
    has_one :subscription
    has_many :creditcards

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :creditcards
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscription
end

class Creditcard < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer

    # needs to run before Subscription before_create callback
    before_create :create_stripe_creditcard
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer

    before_create :create_stripe_subscription
end
```

Comment: Why would the order matter? maybe if you explained a little bit more of what you are wanting to do there might be another solution?

Comment: @user2856118 updated the question, thanks.

Comment: The order in your model will have an impact on your code.
I would assume that your association order decides which nested attribute gets ran first.
Why dont you try changing has_one :subscription to be after has_many :creditcards.

Answer (score 1):

In order to save a `Creditcard` before a `Subscription`, you just need to change the order of associations' declaration.

So the `Customer` model should look like this:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecored::Base
    has_many :creditcards
    has_one :subscription

    ...
end
```